# Charts in .NET and WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, charts

I am developing an application using VS 2010 and WPF...
I need to put a simple 2 line 2D line chart...
However the other developer used WPF toolkit but it didnt work at clients machine...
The grid of the chart was badly disorted (not straight lines!) in windows XP! but running other versions of windows was ok.

I am wondering whats going wrong...

So what are the solutions available for this type of chart ??
Sorry for my question but i have outdated experience with .Net platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WPF toolkit should work on Windows XP, I had success with it.  I'm sure it would be easier to figure out the tech problem of the WPF Toolkit on Windows XP for your client's computer, rather than moving to a different control.

Comment: well they couldnt find it... i will try to my xp installation to check whats going on

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ZedGraph](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/index.html).

I understand you can use the library in a WPF application but I've never tried it.

Comment: is this ok to use to commercial applications?